# How to make object cloning and Manage Windows control to work when Virtual machine is closed in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automationanywhere

I'm trying to test my automation anywhere solution through Scheduling.
Bot. It is working perfectly in the virtual machine when it is triggered manually.
However when i schedule it through control room. Both object Cloning and Manage windows control are failing, since Virtual Machine is not opened manually.
how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Which version of AA are you using? And have you enabled the remote login option from the control room? Finally; Is the bot you are trying to schedule on a runtime or creator license?

Comment: AutoLogin is enabled  and the version 11.1.2

Comment: I am executing the  bot with runner license.Also,Please note that it is windows application

Comment: Any chance you need to go through Citrix to reach the VM?

Comment: Yes..it is a citrix virtual machine.This Citrix virtual machine is accessible from the contrl room and I am able to trigger the Bot from control Room

Answer (score 0):

yea, so there is a problem with AA running on citrix in the disconnected mode. currently there isnt any resolution to it. did you try running the task using RDP connection from control room option?